# Finding a Range based on 2 criteria in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am very, very new to Excel VBA. I'm trying to automate a monthly process. I already have a list on the first tab (tab is named "Data"). The workbook has one other tab named "Sheet2". Only column A will be used. I'm trying to make a macro that begins on cell A1 in the Data tab, finds the 1st instance of my customer number ("06652"), then from there finds the 2nd instance of report name "QE123A.2", and finally highlights a range beginning with that 2nd instance of the report name and ends on the cell which contains the string "***END OF REPORT***".

So I naively thought that I'd just record a relative macro and I'd be done. But, it only goes to the first iteration of the report name and stops there. The process is a little more complex than that, but I'm trying to figure out how to assign the cell location to a variable?

'Finds & populates the very last report!

```
Worksheets("Data").Select
Range("A:A").Select
Cells.Find(What:="06652", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.Find(What:="QE123A.2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Set Report_Range_Start = Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
sROW = sFoundCell.Row - 4
sCOL = sFoundCell.Column
Report_Range_End = "***END OF REPORT***"
Set eFoundCell = WS.Range(Cells(sROW, sCOL), Cells(WS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1)).Find(What:=Report_Range_End)
eROW = eFoundCell.Row
eCOL = eFoundCell.Column
Range(Cells(sROW, sCOL), Cells(eROW, eCOL)).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("CIC06652 - QE123A.2").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I will present is not exactly the fastest or the cleanest way to do what you're asking.

But since you're new, I am proposing it because it's the most straightforward.

Note that you can assign Ranges to Range variables like this:

```vb
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1")
```

But letters are not so easy to loop over, so that's why I'm using numbers instead.

Also notice that you assign values to text (`String`), number (`Integer` or `Long`), and yes / no (`Boolean`) variables with a simple equals sign. But if you want to assign more complicated "Objects" to object variables, you must also use the keyword `Set`.

Here's my solution. I did test it with a version of the scenario you described.

```vb
Public Sub Process()

    Dim searchTabName, customerNumber, reportName, endText As String
    
    searchTabName = "Data"
    customerNumber = "06652"
    reportName = "QE123A.2"
    endText = "***END OF REPORT***"
    
    ' This is column "A" as Excel knows it
    Dim searchColumn As Long
    searchColumn = 1
    
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(searchTabName)
    
    Dim customerNumberFound As Boolean
    customerNumberFound = False
    
    Dim reportNameTimesSeen As Long
    reportNameTimesSeen = 0
    
    Dim startCell, endCell As Range
    
    Dim searchRow As Long
    ' I'm choosing these numbers arbitrarily.
    ' We could do better, but we'd have to know more about your problem.
    ' If we don't find your specific case, then row 5000 is as far as we go.
    For searchRow = 1 To 5000
    
      If customerNumberFound = False And _
          mySheet.Cells(searchRow, searchColumn).Value = customerNumber Then
      
              customerNumberFound = True
          
      ElseIf customerNumberFound = True And _
          reportNameTimesSeen < 1 And _
          mySheet.Cells(searchRow, searchColumn).Value = reportName Then
          
              reportNameTimesSeen = reportNameTimesSeen + 1
        
      ElseIf customerNumberFound = True And _
          reportNameTimesSeen = 1 And _
          mySheet.Cells(searchRow, searchColumn).Value = reportName Then
          
              reportNameTimesSeen = reportNameTimesSeen + 1
              Set startCell = mySheet.Cells(searchRow, searchColumn)
      
      ElseIf customerNumberFound = True And _
          reportNameTimesSeen = 2 And _
          mySheet.Cells(searchRow, searchColumn).Value = endText Then
          
              Set endCell = mySheet.Cells(searchRow, searchColumn)
              mySheet.Activate
              mySheet.Range(startCell, endCell).Select
              Exit Sub

      End If
      
    Next searchRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is the 3rd time I've reviewed your comments and answer and I realize that I have a long way to go before I understand VBA as thoroughly as I would like to if this is the direct explanation. Somehow, I thought that there would be some sort of nested FindNext statement rather than all of these IF statements. I really do appreciate all of the time you've put into my problem!